# Get number of entries from table in specified range

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get number of entries that are greater than some values in other table using MySQL.

I have tables that are similar to these one (but a way bigger):

```
CREATE TABLE test_ranges AS SELECT 'class 1' AS category, 'A' AS grade, 90 AS points;
INSERT INTO test_ranges VALUES ('class 1', 'B', 75),('class 2', 'A', 80);

CREATE TABLE test_results AS SELECT 'class 1' AS category, 100 AS points;
INSERT INTO test_results VALUES ('class 1', 95),('class 1', 94),('class 1', 85),('class 1', 55),('class 1', 44),('class 1', 33);
```

And there is the content of tables:

```
SELECT * FROM test_ranges;

+----------+-------+--------+
| category | grade | points |
+----------+-------+--------+
| class 1  | A     |     90 |
| class 1  | B     |     75 |
| class 2  | A     |     80 |
+----------+-------+--------+
```

And for results:

```
SELECT * FROM test_results;
+----------+--------+
| category | points |
+----------+--------+
| class 1  |    100 |
| class 1  |     95 |
| class 1  |     94 |
| class 1  |     85 |
| class 1  |     55 |
| class 1  |     44 |
| class 1  |     33 |
+----------+--------+
```

I would like to have number of entries for every category for every grade type.

When I try to select using LEFT JOIN it works almost like I want to, but the count is not correct.

```
SELECT test_ranges.category,grade,count(*) FROM test_ranges
  LEFT JOIN test_results USING(category)
  GROUP BY category,grade;

+----------+-------+----------+
| category | grade | count(*) |
+----------+-------+----------+
| class 1  | A     |        7 |
| class 1  | B     |        7 |
| class 2  | A     |        1 |
+----------+-------+----------+
```

When I add `WHERE` clause, I've got right count values, but not every `category` and `grade`:

```
SELECT test_ranges.category,grade,COUNT(*) FROM test_ranges
  LEFT JOIN test_results USING(category)
  WHERE test_results.points>=test_ranges.points
  GROUP BY category,grade;

+----------+-------+----------+
| category | grade | count(*) |
+----------+-------+----------+
| class 1  | A     |        3 |
| class 1  | B     |        4 |
+----------+-------+----------+
```

I would like to have results similar to:

```
+----------+-------+----------+
| category | grade | count(*) |
+----------+-------+----------+
| class 1  | A     |        3 |
| class 1  | B     |        4 |
| class 2  | A     |        0 |
+----------+-------+----------+
```

**EDIT**

I have found that:

```
SELECT test_ranges.category,grade,COUNT(test_results.points) FROM test_ranges
  LEFT JOIN test_results USING(category)
  WHERE test_results.points>=test_ranges.points OR test_results.points IS NULL
  GROUP BY category,grade;
```

returns the right thing. The problem here is only performance. In my original problem, the test_ranges is (query join query) statement that in result gives about 32 rows and test_results has 300k rows.

Comment: I've found solution to improve performance: do select as described in the EDIT (but without OR statment with `IS NULL` test), and put it into subquery with `UNION` with all categories and grades with 0 value in column `c`. The _parent_ query selects everything with column `c` calculated as sum of `c` (so 0 + count(test_results.points)).
**Query**:
`SELECT category, grade, SUM(c) FROM (
    SELECT category, grade, 0 AS c FROM test_grades
  UNION
    SELECT test_ranges...
    WHERE test_results.points>=test_ranges.points
    GROUP BY category,grade) AS foo
GROUP BY foo.category,foo.grade`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `on` clause:

```
select rg.category, rg.grade, ifnull(count(rs.points),0) as num
  from test_ranges rg
  left join test_results rs
       on rg.category = rs.category
      and rs.points >= rg.points
 group by rg.category, rg.grade;
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d503a/4/0

As noted by Gordon your expected result is a little odd though. This shows everyone who scores an A as also scoring a B since they meet that threshold. I'm not sure if that's what you actually want. I guess you could picture it as "the number of people who at least scored a grade of X..." and might be useful in that regard. In any case, just be aware.

Comment: Originally, I wanted to get only number of people who has points in specified range (but range spans for two rows), but I think that is impossible, so I decided to left this for postprocessing (order by points and substract current count value with previous count value).

Comment: It's not impossible, it would actually be easy if mysql had analytic functions  (you could use `lag` to establish the start and end of a score based on the prior row). You could use variables in mysql to achieve the same result, just not nearly as easily. Easiest thing to do -- for that -- would be to have 2 columns on your `test_ranges` table: `min_points` and `max_points` (for each class and grade) Then your select statements would be easy.

Comment: Oh, yes, it's possible but not so easy. The two approach are possible, but for second, when modifying range in one place it requires updating changes in other places.

**Back to topic:**
Your solution is working great, but for real data (300k rows, 32 categories, and only 2 grades) comparing _points_ in `on` clause takes almost 50 seconds to finish, when puting it in `where` clause (that shows partially incorrect values) takes 0.3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Start with `test_ranges` and use a correlated subquery:

```
select tr.category, tr.grade,
       (select count(*)
        from test_results tr2
        where tr2.category = tr.category and
              tr2.points >= tr.points
       ) as cnt
from test_ranges tr;
```

This should actually return what your query returns.

Comment: Grade _B_ for category _class 1_ should be 4, as only 4 rows have 75 or more points.

Comment: @rantir . . . Oops, I misread the data.  It *is* returning a cumulative sum.